# Why does std::atomic_fetch take a pointer as its input parameter

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, atomic, pass-by-pointer

The set of free functions for `std::atomic_fetch_xxx` *(or, and, add, sub, xor)*, take as input a `std::atomic<T>*` named obj:

```
template< class T >
T atomic_fetch_sub(std::atomic<T>* obj,
                   typename std::atomic<T>::difference_type arg ) noexcept;
```

---

Question: Why is the std::atomic type taken as a pointer and not instead passed in as a reference eg:

```
T atomic_fetch_sub(std::atomic<T>& obj,
                   typename std::atomic<T>::difference_type arg ) noexcept;
```

Is there a practical rational/reason or is it simply stylistic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole idea of *having* the free functions is to be compatible with C. You can pretty easily import C code to C++ and make it work the same there (or vice versa).

If you don't want that you can use member functions instead - using references everywhere - for example `obj.fetch_sub(arg)`, or even `obj -= arg` using operator overloading.

But then the code will be C++ only.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does std::atomic_fetch take a pointer as its input parameter

`atomic_fetch_sub` needs to be able to update the value of the first parameter (in case it fails), which requires the first argument to be passed by either pointer or reference.

A pointer was chosen to make it compatible with the C interface.

Comment: why does this function need to be compatible with the C interface?   as an aside it defines a noexcept policy which is not C

Comment: @JMkdjion But C functions don't throw, makes sense to me

Comment: @JMkdjion: "*why does this function need to be compatible with the C interface?*" I don't understand the question. It needs to be compatible with the C interface so that people can more easily write code that can compile as C or C++. That's the point of compatibility. `atomic_fetch_sub(&var, ...)` works whether `var` is a `std::atomic<int>` or `atomic_int`. So you just `#ifdef` around the definition of `var`; you don't have to `#ifdef` around every use of the variable.

Comment: @curiousguy12 the issue is with the use of noexcept keyword in the declaration, as "extern C"-ing that will cause a compiler error.

Comment: @NicolBolas as far as I know C does not support template parameters. As such this free function would be useless in any kind of portable C-C++ context.

Comment: @JMkdjion: No, it doesn't take template parameters. But C11 (which provides the atomic types) does have the concept of ["generic selection"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic), which [`atomic_fetch_sub`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_fetch_sub) uses. Meaning that it will do the right thing for any atomic type passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

These free functions exist for applications to be able to compile as C or C++ without changing most of the code. By taking a pointer, calling the free function would look like `atomic_fetch_add(var, ...)`. This is also why `atomic_int` exists in C++, though it has a different definition than the C version.

C11 achieves this kind of function overloading by using [generic selection macros](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic). [`atomic_fetch_add` in C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_fetch_add) is not a function; it's a macro that selects which function to call based on the type of one of its parameters.